# Still overheating

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

I have a 03 civic ex replaced radiator thermostat still overheating and the last time it overheated I got a greyish sludge come out of the radiator cap. Can someone help?

Comment: You could consider flushing the system - to remove any impurities / sludge which sounds like is in there.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How does it behave when it's overheating? I mean, are you basing the overheating diagnosis off of what the dash gauge says? When it does overheat, is it "okay" then all of a sudden spikes up to well over normal temperature? Does the radiator itself boil over? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

if "greyish sludge" is what I think it is, you blew a head gasket when you overheated it.  The greyish sludge is motor oil.  It sludges when mixed with antifreeze